# Doctrine: Keep 'Timestampable' behavior when using stored procedures?

Tags: stored-procedures, doctrine

I have **complex logic** which is not possible (too slow) to run through PHP with Doctrine, so I need to create a **stored procedure** for this. The logic also includes *inserting/updating* records in a table using the **[Timestampable](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/hu/behaviors#core-behaviors:timestampable) behavior**. **How do I preserve this behavior in the stored procedure?**

Comment: Which database, mysql, mssql ?

Comment: I'm using mysql (on a separate server, hence the question..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your schema uses the default Timestampable behaviour from Doctrine, then you have the `created_at` and `updated_at` datetime columns added to your table schema.  Then I'd imagine that in your stored procedure, you can update both `created_at` and `updated_at` to the current date & time (using eg `NOW()`) if the record is new, and only `updated_at` if the record is existing.

This assumes that your stored procedure can differentiate between new and existing records.

Comment: No this won't work, the `NOW()` function in Mysql uses the datetime on the db server and the `time()` function in PHP uses the datetime on the application server. There is always an offset between both timestamps (which is not acceptable by design).

Comment: Ah I see.  How are you calling your stored procedure - manually from PHP via direct SQL? Could you not pass in `time()` as a parameter?